# axis2 mtom mime boundary

Tags: android, soap, apache-axis, mime, mtom

I have a axis2 client created using ADB binding. 
This axis2 client talks to a WCF webservice, sending it a XML attachment in a MTOM mode.
The SOAP Request generated is:

```
POST http://xyz/mtom HTTP/1.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
type="application/xop+xml";
start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";
boundary="uuid:0daa5c61-46d2-4fe1-9944-097b897367b4+id=1";
start-info="application/soap+xml"; 
action="http://blahblah/SendData"
Host: myserver.org
Content-Length: 22648
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

--uuid:0daa5c61-46d2-4fe1-9944-097b897367b4+id=1
 Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
```

How can I make the Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary(below) to Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit?

```
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
 Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="application/soap+xml"

 <s:Envelope><s:Body><SendData>...</SendData></s:Body></s:Envelope>
 --uuid:0daa5c61-46d2-4fe1-9944-097b897367b4+id=1
 Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/634789954872318389>
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
 Content-Type: application/octet-stream

 Serialized payload here
 --uuid:0daa5c61-46d2-4fe1-9944-097b897367b4+id=1--
```

Also, I guess one mime_boundary is for the main soap envelope and the second mime_boundary is for the attachment

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, and there is a good reason for that. The `8bit` encoding is defined as follows:

> up to 998 octets per line with CR and LF (codes 13 and 10 respectively) only allowed to appear as part of a CRLF line ending.

This implies that there are messages that cannot be encoded as `8bit`. Axis2 would have to check  that the message can be encoded as `8bit` before starting to write it. This would introduce an unnecessary overhead. Therefore, Axis2 only supports `binary` and `base64` because they allow to encode any message (and they are expected to be supported by any SOAP stack).

Anyways, why would you want it to use `8bit`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had to use 8bit encoding because the WCF webservice actually expects it.

Comment: Also, I do see references to 8 bit encoding in few forums. So, that keeps me looking out. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-2236